# GROUP BY in Django ORM with aggregation

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I need to implement such query:

```
Table1
|Id | Name   |
| 1 | Peter  |
| 2 | Andrew |

Table2
| Score | Table1Id |
| 10    | 1        |
| 20    | 1        |
| 100   | 1        |
| 0     | 2        |
| 30    | 2        |
```

I need select for all names {name, min_score, max_score}

```
{Peter, 10, 100}
{Andrew, 0, 30}
```

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(score), MAX(score) Table1.name FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id GROUP BY Table1.Name
```

In ORM it something like:

```
Table2.objects.all().annotate(min_score=Min('score'), max_score=Max('score')).values('Table1.Name!!!!', 'min_score', 'max_score')
```

Comment: you should post the model definitions - you have a foreignkey from Table2 to Table1 ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Table2.objects.values('table1__name').annotate(min_score=Min('score'), max_score=Max('score'))
```

the annotated fields will be added to the result, they don't need to go in `values(...)`, but whatever you put in `values(...)` will be used as the `GROUP BY` field(s)